# Change Resource Dictionary in runtime

Tags: wpf, resources, material-design, runtime, resourcedictionary

I use Material design in my wpf. I change theme(Light/Dark) in runtime.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog">
  <materialDesign:DialogHost.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="materialDesign:Card" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:Card}}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.dark.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCardBackground}" />
    </Style>
  </materialDesign:DialogHost.Resources>
  <Grid>
      <!--some code-->
  </Grid>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

I want change source of Resource Dictionary in runtime to

```
pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.light.xaml
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Define your Resource dictionary Apllication wide in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- This is the default theme (useful for Designing)-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.dark.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Change the Theme in code behind.

```
public Skin ChangeSkin()
        {
            // you might want to have some logic here to keep switching
 ApplyResources("pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.light.xaml")
        }

private void ApplyResources(string src)
        {
            App a = App.Current as App;
            var dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(src, UriKind.Relative) };
            foreach (var mergeDict in dict.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                a.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(mergeDict);
            }

            foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
            {
                a.Resources[key] = dict[key];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want this change set on the `materialDesign:Card` because in change correct, also in `MainWindow's Cards` but in the `DialogHost` don't changed